# GPU Basic : Why handle Floating point numbers for computer graphics

Tags: graphics, floating-point, gpu, gpgpu

I am just learning on GPU and in this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGmPy8xpT4E&t=4278s) as well as other architecture diagrams of GPU, each Streaming multiprocessor is shown to have multiple ALUs. But in my understanding ALUs can handle only Integer numbers whereas GPUs must handle floating numbers for which multpile FPUs would be desired. Why does the architecture specify ALUs then?

Secondly, for graphics, what is the need for handling floating point numbers? I cannot comprehend a pixel or co-ordinate position in a screen being a floating point number?

PS: I understand its a very basic question, but I am unable to find out a proper resource/answer yet on these despite having read many articles/videos for GPUs.

Comment: You may find that float are more convenient as soon as you want to use arbitrary scale, arbitrary projection of 3D objects, etc...

Comment: It is also simpler to do trigonometry calculations in float than integer.

Comment: and floats are just 2 integers packed together ... mantissa and exponent ... one is used more or less as standard integer the other is just bit shift ... so to handle float you need ALU + bitshifting  all perfectly doable on integers

Comment: @Spektre That makes perfect sense and now i undestand why the ALU is also mentioned as a fundamental block of FPU https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit. Thanks a bunch...